# StackView within StackView - Overlapped Views

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, simulator, stackview

I have been trying to put together a view using Stack Views. The layout looks acceptable within Xcode but the 2nd, 3rd and 4th rows seem to overlap a small area when reviewed in the simulator.

There are some autolayout warnings and if I autofix one issue (Fix misplacement > Update frames) others appear. I basically end up toggling between placement issues. I must be fixing them in the wrong way.

1. Is there anything obviously wrong?
2. Why are these views overlapping each other?
3. What strategy should I use to fix the misplacement issues?

[image]
[image: Structure]
[image: Compacted view]

Comment: It's difficult to tell what layout you want, and which view each warning is referring to, because all of your labels have the text `Label` and all of your buttons have the title `Button`. Set the text and titles so that the appearance in the canvas matches the names in the warning list.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry, hopefully the updated label text helps.

Comment: O, The layout that I am trying to achieve for now is exactly how it looks in interface builder. Thanks.